# Nexus-compliant repository to get node and npm installers

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, nexus, package-managers

I am looking for a nexus-compliant repository where I can get a node installer (a nexus-compliant alternative to http://nodejs.org/dist/.

**Context :**

In a java environment, our builds are processed by maven. Recently we add a javascript frontend app and I am trying to get it built via maven with the excellent plugin [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin).

The plugin installs node and npm, then run `npm install` and `grunt build`.
Everything works perfectly.

But we MUST put all our dependencies under nexus (or some locally proxified repository).

- About frontend dependencies: no problem since nexus 2.10 supports the npm registries. It works.
- About the node and npm installers, they are initially downloaded from http://nodejs.org/dist/ by the plugin, and I do not know how to locally proxify this repo ... or where I can find theses installers on a nexus-compliant's one.

Any suggestions ?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create a pull request/patch for the frontend plugin that allows you to add a full url for npm and node rather than just the version and the root url. Then you can host the two installed e.g. by uploading them to Nexus into a Maven 2 repository and using that URL. I filed an issue for that btw. https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/126

Alternatively could try to create a site repository in Nexus with the same structure and use that.

Comment: Thx for your answer (and the issue). I am trying to create a site repository. I set it up to be a mirror of the original distant site "nodejs.org/dist" ... but it does not seem to work. I am new in all that stuffs, I probably miss something somewhere.

Comment: You can not mirror it. If you set up a site repo, you have to manually upload the file you want there.. and then you can access that url. The site repo just allows you yo use any structure ... including the one from nodejs.

Comment: I know but I am not familiar with java, so adding a site repository did seem easier at first sight. I think I will finally go for the PR, it souldn't be too complicated.

Comment: Hum ... Maybe I am stupid, but I cannot stand not making this f*ck*ng site repository mirroring work! I like to understand why I am wrong, because sometimes I am not! :p

Comment: Mirroring is NOT going to work. It is not designed to proxy off the  remote repository. Like I mentioned you have to MANUALLY upload the remote repo into the site repository.

Comment: Yes, I misread your first answers. Thx for your time. I will do that.

Comment: @ManfredMoser How do you go about manually uploading binary files to a site repo on Nexus? I create the site repo just fine but can't find anyway of getting these NodeJS binaries into the repo via the Nexus GUI. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to upload them via http put requests.